# convolutional neural network (CNN) for text classification

Tags: text, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, text-classification

I am using CNN for text classification, in my model after flatten layer I used output layer directly without using dense layer. is that correct or must use dense layer?

just as example:

```
model.add(Conv1D(filters=100, kernel_size=2,,padding='same' ,activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: You dont need any dense layer between flatten and output layer. what you have done is right. You can verify this on completely unseen dataset.

Comment: Thanks @adityathakkar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you do not have to use a Dense layer. As the outputs of your convolution do contain some spatial information, though, it might make sense to use one.

I am assuming that you already understood how a convolution works. In that case, imagine what the activations at a certain position in the sentence mean, with regards to the end result in classification.

There are even End-to-End-CNNs, as for example GoogleNet, which (as the name indicates), also does not have a fully connected layer.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Its helpful